# Find coordinate of HTML5 canvas matching given color

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need a way to find the coordinates of each pixel that have a specific color. I could loop through every pixel in the entire image and check if that matches, but that doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to loop through the array as that is the only way to evaluate all the pixels in the canvas.

However, you can use 32-bit integer (typed) array instead of the standard 8-bit array - that will be many times faster:

```
var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height),
    buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer),
    len = buffer32.length,
    i = 0, x, y,
    color = 0xffffffff;   /// white color (ABGR format on little-endian systems)

for(; i < len; i++) {
    if (buffer32[i] === color) {
         /// convert i to x/y position here
         x = i % idata.width;
         y = (i / idata.height)|0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed a comma between y and w on the first line. Do I need to use ABGR for the color format, or can I use standard hex? Other than `ctx` and my color I'm searching for, is there anything else I need to change to make it work for me? Thank you.

Comment: @Keavon with typed array you need to use ABGR (0xAABBGGRR in hex representation) for little endian systems (most main-stream systems are little endian today so this won't be any problem). RGBA for big-endian. This is because these are low-level (typed) arrays and there won't be a conversion (you can of course use the equivalent of the hex value as 32-bit integer instead if you wish). Other than that, push x and y to an array or create an object when you get a hit and you should be good to go!

Comment: If I don't need the alpha, can I use BGR? Or do I just need to put 00 in front of it? I've never really heard of ABGR before. Do I simply add 00 then the last two hex characters of my HEX code, then the middle two, then the first two?

Comment: @Keavon ABGR is just the order of the bytes, first the alpha byte, then blue etc. If you don't need alpha you will still need to set it. If you set 0 the color will be transparent so use ff, for example a cyan/green color will look like this `0xffff7f00`, an orange: `0xff007fff`, a green `0xff00ff00`, red `0xff0000ff` and so on. Notice the first `0xff......` is the alpha channel. Don't forget to upvote/accept if answer helped! :)

Comment: I'm getting two undefined values in the array. Would you mind looking over this, please? http://pastebin.com/SduQygMf

Comment: @Keavon you need to provide a fiddle - a pastebin does not much. debugging service is not really a part of answering on SO.. ;-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wm2zP/ And yeah, sorry, I know debugging isn't what SO is for but hopefully you don't mind :) We could also move this to chat if you'd like. Function is at the very bottom of the script, and it's called on line 72. Call it by adding text to the existing text in the input box.